# Generating a 'unique' 3 character tag from 4 Hex digits

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, unique-key

I'm working on a project using `Raspberry Pi` in a stateless net booted environment for a local museum.  I want the `Raspberry Pi` to generate an easy to remember 3 character code from the last 4 digits of the MAC address.  This code will be read by a person and input into a database describing what the machine will do, and on future reboots the `Raspberry Pi` will look up its own code to identify it's tasks.

It could be done with part of the MAC address alone, but I would like to generate a more human compatible code to reduce errors.  The conversion only has to work in one direction.

I think I've broken it down into logical steps, but I'm not sure how I could implement them in an efficient way.

1. Take the last 4 chars from the MAC address
2. Convert to binary - 16 bits
3. Delete MSB to leave 15 bits
4. Reverse the order of the bits - in my mind this would randomize the characters a bit more to make the final string more memorable
5. Break the 15 bits into 3 chunks of 5 bits
6. Map each 5 bit chunk to a letter/number skipping I,1,O & 0 to avoid confusion
7. Output the 3 character string

Comment: So basically, you need a 3 character hash of 6 byte data, right? Typically, first 3 digits are 'conventionally' linked to the vendor id & would be same across different `Raspberry Pi` boards. So you could just strip out the first 3 bytes & use last 3 bytes as hash.

Comment: Yes - I think.  But I'd be willing to only use 4 bytes if I could improve the human readability of the end result.

Comment: BAsed on the hash suggestion I'm looking at hashids - http://hashids.org/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked through the responses above and came up with a solution.  It's not perfect, but it works...

```
if [ ! -f /home/pi/MAC_ADDRESS ]; then
    BASE28="ABC3DEFG4HJK6LMN7PQRT8UVW9XY";
    arg1=$(ifconfig | grep eth0 | awk '{if ($4 == "HWaddr") print $5 }');
    echo $arg1 > /home/pi/MAC_ADDRESS;
    arg1="${arg1//:}";
    arg1=${arg1:8:4};
    arg1=$(echo $arg1 | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]');
    arg1=$(bc <<< "obase=28; ibase=16; $arg1");
    c="";
    for i in $arg1; do
        if [ $i -eq 08 ]; then
            i=8;
        fi
        if [ $i -eq 09 ]; then
            i=9;
        fi 
        b=${BASE28:$i:1};
        c=$c$b;
    done
    c=${c:(-3)};
    echo $c > /home/pi/CLIENT_ID;
fi
```

In the for loop I needed to fix the 08 and 09 for some reason...

Answer (score 1):

You can divide the last 13 bits into groups of 5, 3, 5 bits. Choose a consonant letter using the first and the last (there are 21, needing 5 bits, and you can repeat from 22), and choose a vowel letter for the middle 3 (there are 5, same way of choosing). This will give mostly pronunciable "names", and some of them may be hilarious too.